# fractal returns null to object inside object laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm using fractal transformation. my User table has a column named avatar which is array of arrays like that

```
{"thumbnail":{"url":"\/storage\/images\/user\/2019\/10\/03\/54\/53\/50x50_crop\/ZdkTk1UGyQAS60C4.png","height":50,"width":50},"xsmall":{"url":"\/storage\/images\/user\/2019\/10\/03\/54\/53\/160x120\/ZdkTk1UGyQAS60C4.png","height":120,"width":82},"small":{"url":"\/storage\/images\/user\/2019\/10\/03\/54\/53\/240x180\/ZdkTk1UGyQAS60C4.png","height":180,"width":124}}
```

when I transofrme User object it returns null

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {

            "avatar": {
                "thumbnail": null,
                "xsmall": {},
                "small": {},
            },
        }
    }
}
```

my tranformation code is

```
public function transform(User $user)
    {
        return [
            'avatar' =>  [
                'thumbnail' => $user->avatar->thumbnail->url,
                'xsmall' => url($user->avatar->xsmall->url),
                'small' => url($user->avatar->small->url),

            ]

        ];
    }
```

however without tranformation here is the result

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "avatar": {
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "/storage/images/user/2019/10/09/03/28/50x50_crop/Z2ecpS7BmRJsFVSc.png",
                    "height": 50,
                    "width": 50
                },
                "xsmall": {
                    "url": "/storage/images/user/2019/10/09/03/28/160x120/Z2ecpS7BmRJsFVSc.png",
                    "height": 120,
                    "width": 120
                },
                "small": {
                    "url": "/storage/images/user/2019/10/09/03/28/240x180/Z2ecpS7BmRJsFVSc.png",
                    "height": 180,
                    "width": 180
                },

            }
```

}

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Where is the user object coming from?

Comment: @saly from controller  ` $user = Auth::user();
                $user = fractal($user, new UserTransformer($this->helperService))->toArray();`